# Where to download dynamics demonstration videos for motion analysis?

Tags: data-request, video

I'm looking for videos of demonstrations/experiments of dynamics for download. Also they should be clear and of good quality.

I want to use them in a video analysis program (https://www.cabrillo.edu/~dbrown/tracker/). Ideally, they should be

Camera on tripod to fix origin.
plain background for tracking objects
be well lit - should have shorter shutter speed, ie less blur
have decent resolution
be at least 30 fps
be available for download
Some sources are

MIT - http://video.mit.edu/watch/double-pendulum-6392/
Youtube, for example, 
But these aren't available for download, and aren't always up to the lab standards above.